# What leads to "Could not find QtWebEngineProcess" error?

Tags: c++, qt, linker, qt5, qtwebengine

I am triyng to port WebKit (Qt5.5.1) plugin to WebEngine (Qt5.11.3) one as described here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-qtwebkitportingguide.html
Building and running in Ubuntu 18.04 I get following errors:

```
QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled
```

and then

```
Could not find QtWebEngineProcess
```

I am not sure if first one is related to second but second one leads to crash.

**EDIT**:
I put QtWebEngineProcess from `Qt/libexec` dir to dir with binary and now second error changed to:

```
WebEngineContext used before initialize() or OpenGL context creation failed.
```

still crashes.

Comment: Maybe related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46189370/qtwebengineprocess-error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was in missed dependency files.

Our `cmake` build copied only auto-determined dependencies (libs) from the Qt folder to the app folder. But for a full deploy a QtWebEngine app needs few non-libs dependencies such as `QtWebEngineProcess` executable `xcbglintegrations` plugins (first error) and WebEngine resources. This instruction https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-deploying.html have most of details.

It worked for me with Qt5.12.9. With Qt5.11.3 I still had some problem.